# Secured JEE app with Keycloak have the SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal() anonymous

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, keycloak

I have a JEE Service (JaxRx) secured with Keycloak, the authentication works, but when I want to apply security with `@RolesAllowed` I got `EJBAccessException`.

The service is deployed in Wildfly 11 and regarding the documentation, I propagated the security context to the EJB tier with `@SecurityDomain("keycloak")` and the next config file(`jboss-ejb3.xml`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:jboss
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
    version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">

  <assembly-descriptor>
    <s:security>
      <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
      <s:security-domain>keycloak</s:security-domain>
    </s:security>
  </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:jboss>
```

I installed the keycloak `security-domain` in Wildfly.

I was checking and I saw the SessionContext does not have the user, but the Web Context has it.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the requesting user is identified in the RequestContext but in the SessionContext (context) is not present, it shows `anonymous` instead of the user.

Some ideas what could be missing in my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case was missing the `jboss-web.xml` file in my `WEB-INF` folder.

I added a file named `jboss-web.xml` with the below content and work like a charm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss>
    <security-domain>keycloak</security-domain>
</jboss>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue because my EJB were not secure. It's mandatory to use either @PermitAll or @RolesAllowed annotation to secure the EJB. Without one of those annotations the user principal that you can retrieve from the EjbContext will be anonymous.